# Can't establish connection to the MySQL during gitlab ci-cd job: UnknownHostException: mysql: Name or service not known

Tags: java, spring-boot, gitlab

**TASK:**

- I want to deploy my project via GitLab CI-CD process.
- This is logically I need have opportunity to execute tests of this project during deploying.

**ISSUE:**

- I am receiving `UnknownHostException: mysql: Name or service not known` during test execution, **however** I do not need to use MySQL connection during test.

---

So:

- gitlab-ci.yml:

```
run-test:
  image: gradle:7.2.0-jdk17
  script:
    - gradle :business:test
```

- test:

```java
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
public class PersonControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void businessHealthCheckTest(){
        log.info("Test started");
        Assertions.assertThat(true).isTrue();
        log.info("Test finished");
    }
}
```

As I understand, I receive this error, since I use `@SpringBootTest` annotation, and it means the Spring tries establish connection to the database. So, I researched and found such "solution", that I added to the .yml file:

```yaml
run-test:
  image: gradle:7.2.0-jdk17
  services:
    - mysql:latest
  variables:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: "my_test_db"
    MYSQL_USER: "test_user"
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: "test_password"
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root_password"
  script:
    - gradle :business:test
```

and I also updated connection string in application.properties file (I changed localhost:3306 to the mysql:3306):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/my_test_db?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

But I still can't execute tests with deploying process.

So, probably, two question:

1. Why do I need establish connection if I do not use DB connection during tests? How to avoid this, but use `@SpringBootTest` annotation.
2. Main question: How to correctly use this mysql `service` in my case?

Comment: Consider using H2 in-memory embedded database for integration tests only.

Comment: @Mar-Z problem in that - in general, I don't need DB for tests. That is the main issue - why test ask database connection if I don't need it.